# Show that $D(f)$ is a basis for the topology on $ \mathbb{P^n} $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We give $\mathbb P^n$ the quotient topology from the standard map from $\mathbb A^{n+1}- \{0\}$. I want to show that $D(f)$ where $f$ is a homogenous polynomial, forms a basis for the open sets of $\mathbb P^n$.

It seems there are two approaches we can go:

We could show directly that the $D(f)$ cover projective space and show that the property about intersections. The property about intersections is easy since $D(f)\cap D(g)=D(fg)$. However it is not obvious that these $D(f)$ cover projective space. In the affince case it is easy since we can take $f=(x_1-a_1)..(x_n-a_n)$ and then $D(f)$ contains $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$. But such an $f$ is not going to be homogenous.

How can we make a homogenous polynomial such that it vanishes on $(a_0:..:a_n)$.

Secondly, is there a way to use that we know $D(f)$ form a basis for $\mathbb A^{n+1}$? It seems like we might be able to say something like $r:\mathbb A^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb A^{n+1}- \{0\}$ followed by $q:\mathbb A^{n+1}-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb P^n$ sends the basis $D(f)$ to the basis $D(f')$ where $f'$ is homogenous.

Comment: Hi, what is D(f)?

Comment: Sorry I thought this was common notation. $D(f)$ is the set of points where $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: But then $D(f)$ is a dense set in $\mathbb{P}^n$ for all $f$ right? So this cannot be a basis of the usual topology in $\mathbb{P}^n$. I don´t know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: We give affine space the Zariski topology and projective space the quotient topology coming from this. So yes the non empty open sets will be dense

Comment: Ohh sorry, I misunderstood. I was thinking in terms of the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Covering the whole space is pretty trivial, since $D(1)$ is the whole space. To get a homogeneous polynomial vanishing on a given point $(a_0:a_1:\ldots:a_n)$, represent it as $(1:a_1':\ldots, a_n')$, find a non-homogeneous one vanishing on $(a_1',\ldots,a_n')$ and homogenize it.